# Cannot open file with relative path? (C++ ifstream)

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode6, relative-path, ifstream

I know this seems like a simple question, but I tried everything I can think of to no avail to something that shouldn't have been a problem in the first place.

This is a small C++ program that opens a file. When I open it with its absolute filepath, it works fine. With a relative path, however, it stops working.

Here's the file path of the program and the files I'm trying to read:

**C++ program:** `"/Users/Baggio/C++/Lab0/Lab0/Lab0/main.cpp"`

**Files:** `/Users/Baggio/C++/Lab0/Lab0/Lab0/result.txt`, `/Users/Baggio/C++/Lab0/Lab0/Lab0/dict.txt`

**Here's the code snippet:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip> 
#include <string> 
#include <cstdlib> 
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

//    string dict_filename = "/Users/Baggio/C++/Lab0/Lab0/Lab0/dict.txt";
//    string result_filename = "/Users/Baggio/C++/Lab0/Lab0/Lab0/result.txt";

    string dict_filename_string = "dict.txt";
    string result_filename_string = "result.txt";

    const char* dict_filename = dict_filename_string.c_str();
    const char* result_filename = result_filename_string.c_str();

    //  open files
    ifstream dict_file(dict_filename, ifstream::in);
    ifstream result_file(result_filename, ifstream::in);

    if (!dict_file || !result_file) {
        cerr << "File could not be opened." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

**Result of execution**

```
File could not be opened.
```

I'm sure I've done all the includes right, and the data types right for the ifstream constructor arguments. The only thing I can think of worth mentioning is the system I'm on: **I'm on a Mac and I'm using XCode6 as my IDE.**

Also, I've tried to move the files' location (results.txt and dict.txt) to these locations to no avail:

```
/Users/Baggio/C++/Lab0/Lab0/Lab0/

/Users/Baggio/C++/Lab0/Lab0/

/Users/Baggio/C++/Lab0/

/Users/Baggio/C++/
```

Thanks for your help guys!! Any suggestions or thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Yeah that's right! Typo bad mistake... -__-"

Comment: I'd add the xcode tag, as I think that may be where the issue is - the path where the program is run may not the the source file location. You also might try having the file path string be like "./dict.txt".

Comment: Yup added - I've also tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: Hmm can you try a function to create a file, specify a relative path, and if that succeeds, search for where the file gets created?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Print out your current working directory when you run the program:

```
char buffer[256];
char *val = getcwd(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
if (val) {
    std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
}
```

This will tell you where you are running your program from and thus why the path doesn't match for relative paths. A relative path is relative to the current working directory, *not* to where your binary is located.

If you want to make the path relative to the location of the binary then you will have to do that yourself. Many programming languages offer this as an option, but it is not built-in to C++. You can do this by finding the executable using the `argv[0]` from `main`. Then you need to drop the file component of the executable path and replace it with the file name that you are interested in.

Since C++17, you can use [`std::filesystem::current_path()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path) instead of `getcwd`.

```
std::cout << std::filesystem::current_path() << std::endl;
```

Comment: I see - so that's where the problem was. It printed `/Users/Baggio/C++/Lab0/Lab0/Lab0/Lab0/Build/Products/Debug` - seems like a problem particular to XCode. I'm now investigating how to change this in XCode. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: How do I use `getcwd` in WIndows 10 with VSC ? Because right now all I get is this: `identifier "getcwd" is undefinedC/C++(20)`

Comment: `getcwd` is a POSIX function. For standard C++, you can use `std::filesystem::current_path` which is defined in the `<filesystem>` header since C++17.